# MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE: Fetch Previous Frame Button Missing

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm currently learning about pagination using MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE, so I've set the row limit to 10 and can only find the fetch next frame of records, but where is the fetch previous frame of records? Is this a bug of MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE?

If it is a bug, do you have a recommendation for switching to another free app? I'm just a student without income at the moment.

[image]

Comment: By the way, I have twenty-one rows. And the image I've provided shows the FIRST frame of records

Comment: Oh sorry, the link that says "enter image description here" is the screenshot I took of MySQL workbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL Workbench doesn't support paging on its own. You can have it apply a LIMIT clause automatically, to limit the number of records that get transfered, or add a LIMIT clause yourself, which you can change to get a part of the full table content.